# Is calling Future#get(time, timeunit) directly (without checking isDone()) a bad practice?

Tags: java, concurrency, future, java.util.concurrent, concurrent-programming

This code runs some really cheap (in terms of time) method in a separate thread, so it's guaranteed with a 99.9999% certainty that the outer method will return successfully. If time it takes to finish the job is more than 5 seconds, I wish to terminate the execution anyway. So, does the code below need some wrapping in `if (future.isDone()) ...` etc or under my circumstances I can leave it as is?

```
final Future<SubE> futureEffect = threadPool.submit(effectCallable(lhs, rhs));
try {
    return futureEffect.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
} catch (InterruptedException | TimeoutException e) {
    throw new eRuleLoadingFailed(e.getMessage());
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
    if (e.getCause() instanceof eAccessDenied) {
        throw (eAccessDenied)e.getCause();
    } else {
        throw new eRuleLoadingFailed(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not need `isDone` here. In fact it would destry your code. In the rare case that the executed code finishes a microsecond AFTER the main thread gets to the `if`, `isDone` would return `false` and the `get` would not be executed at all. I think this is not what you want. You want to execute `get` in all cases.